# RXJS - Observable.do is not working

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs5

I'm trying to return an Observable with a do statment.
for some reason the do statment is not invoked.
Any help will be appreicated:

```js
 public addTarget(video: VideoFile, language?: Language): Observable<Language> {
    if (!this.isTargetCollectionDeclared(video)) {
      video.metadata = video.metadata || <BaseVideoData>{};
      video.metadata.to = [];
    }

    let wasLanguageProvided = language != null;
    if (wasLanguageProvided) {
      video.metadata.to.push(language);
      return Observable.of(language);
    }

    return this._getDefaultFromAvilableLanguages(video)
        .do(languageOrNull => {
          // code is not reaching her
          if (languageOrNull != null) {
            video.metadata.to.push(languageOrNull)
          }
        })
  }
```

Comment: Are you subscribing to the observable?

Comment: how do you call `addTarget`?

Comment: addTarget().subscribe()

Comment: this.videoLanguagesService.addTarget(video)
      .subscribe(addedLangaugeOrNull => {
        if (addedLangaugeOrNull == null) {
          alert("New langauges are coming soon");
        }
      })

Comment: My mistake. It was called from another place from the view. Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observables are lazy, like functions. They won't run unless you subscribe to them, similarly to how functions won't execute until you call them.

Callback passed to `.do` will be executed once the observable is fired, which can happen only once you've subscribed to it.

Comment: My mistake. It was called from another place from the view. Thank you very much

Comment: @user3554268 so how does this answer solve your problem? If it's a typo/mistake of your own, you should delete the question.

Comment: What if I don't need the result of the observable. can I make it invoke without subscrbing to it?

Comment: @echonax I didn't know that do is lazy loaded. It wasn't a typo. I thought it will be invoked without the need to subscribe it.

Comment: @user3554268 but you said you are subscribing in the comment section.

Comment: @echonax I already stated that I was wrong about it .It was called from another place and not from the place I thought it was. sorry for the confusing

Comment: @user3554268, all operators are lazy, not just `do`

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the input argument `video` inside a `.do()` operator created inside a function only after the async internal `_getDefaultFromAvilableLanguages` function emits a value is pretty smelly.

This will most likely result in difficult to debug race conditions with regards to the language being present on the video object or not in the expected moment. I would suggest you to refactor this to be more pure and return an updated VideoFile:

```js
function enrichVideoWithLanguage(video: VideoFile, language?: Language): Observable<VideoFile> {
  // make sure the metadata object is in the expected state
  if (!this.isTargetCollectionDeclared(video)) {
    video.metadata = video.metadata || <BaseVideoData>{};
    video.metadata.to = [];
  }

  return Observable.of(video)
    .mergeMap(
      (video) => {
        if(language) {
          return Observable.of(language)
            .toArray();
        }
        return this._getDefaultFromAvilableLanguages(video)
          .filter(lang => lang != null)
          .toArray()
      },
      (video, languages: Language[]) => {
        // we used toArray to only modify the video object once
        languages.forEach(lang => video.metadata.to.push(language));
        return video;
      }
    );
}
```

This is still a bit smelly because the original input VideoFile will get modified inside this function but at least will help you make sure that the videoFile being emitted by `enrichVideoWithLanguage` will contain the language values you expect directly after emitting.